# Platform specific XAML not working for wasm

Tags: xaml, uno-platform, uno

Included wasm in the page namespaces like this:
xmlns:wasm="http://uno.ui/wasm"

and in the ignorable like this:
`mc:Ignorable="d wasm"`

then included an image that I only want displayed in WASM:
`<wasm:Image  MaxWidth="193" MaxHeight="193" Source="ms-appx:///FinchoiceMobi/Assets/Images/QR_Code.png"  Grid.Row="3" Margin="0, 0, 0, 10" />`

The image does not work in WASM in Chrome, but as soon as remove the wasm part of the Image, then it loads the images in wasm.

Any ideas why this is not working?

Trying to have the image only display in wasm.`your text`